# Scopes in Angularjs directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

Let's say I have this setup:

Directive:

```
angular.module('App.directives').directive( 'createCourseStep1' , function(){
return {
    restrict : 'E',
    replace: 'true',
    templateUrl : 'lib/courses/templates/create-course-step-1.html',
    scope :{
        slideNum : '@'
    },
    link : function(scope , elem , attrs){
      scope.slideNum = attrs.slidenum;
    }
}})
```

View (directive rendered):

```
<div class="create-course-info-wrapper" ng-show="$parent.currentSlide == slideNum"></div>
```

on Controller:

```
$scope.currentSlide = 1;
```

Is there a way that I don't have to refer in the view to the currentSlide as "$parent"? I only used this setup because I was having difficulty to access the "attrs.slideNum" in the view. It was working if I was printing the value `{{slideNum}}` but when I wanted to `... ng-show="showStep(slideNum)"` the value was undefined. I ask this because I'm using another directive inside that directive which means I have to do $parent.$parent, just wondering if this is the best practice. Thank you!

Comment: Wait, why is the directive itself trying to show itself?  Why not just add a `visible` property to the isolate scope and have the consuming HTML (parent HTML) determine the logic at that level?

Comment: Just pass both of these parameters to the directive. One can be static (i.e. does not need to be $watched for changes)

Comment: I think passing both the parameters will not solve it, because inside I'm using more variables from the parent scope, but I see your point, it will resolve it as long as I pass in the parameters I'm going to be using. Can be a solution. ryanyuyu, could you explain what you mean I don't get it. You are saying to do this logic - $parent.currentSlide == slideNum inside the directive and control the visible property from there?

Comment: 'inside I'm using more variables from the parent scope' - and you shouldn't. Isolated scope (which you are using) implies that all scope properties from outside are fed to the directive via attributes, which makes the directive self-contained.